# are function calls evaluated as a value in python?

Tags: python

let's say that I define a function.

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

And then I assing the returned value to a variable.

```
x = add(5, 6)
```

Or use the function as argument to another function like.

```
abs(add(5, 6))
```

is the function then evaluated as a value or I missing something?

Comment: When you call `add(5,6)`, it is evaluating to `11`, and you are passing the number `11` to the function `abs()`. You are not passing the `add` function to another function.

Comment: **return**, the value is *returned* to where the function was called, so `add(5,6)` is evaluated to the value returned by the function.

Comment: What do you mean by *"evaluated as a value"*? Functions are first-class in Python, so you can pass them to other functions, but in this case you're passing its output.